# Call JavaScript function from dart

Tags: flutter

Is anyone know how to call JS function from dart ?
I followed steps which linked below.

Firstly, appear this error.
`"Error: Not found: 'dart:js' import 'dart:js';"`
I followed previous answer which comment this line from js.dart and fixed it.
[export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;].

But now I got another error below.

`No top-level method 'callJsFunc' declared. Receiver: top-level Tried calling: callJsFunc()`

Is anyone know how to fix this error ?

[text](https://zenn.dev/tsukatsuka1783/articles/5635db7b9b08d4)

I tried other Flutter SDK version (latest one and 3.0.5) but got same error.

Answer (score 0):

`flutter` uses `dart` not `javascript`.
so... actually you require a separate `javascript engine` if you want to use `javascript` with `flutter` and that can be done with `dart ffi` unless you are building a `web app` with `flutter`.

However, there is a library called [flutter_js](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js) and you can use it if you need to run `javascript`.

On the other hand, if you are interested in using `embeddable Javascript engine` with your `flutter` project by yourself.

you should check this [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-ffigen) out where it shows how to use `ffi` for attaching an `embeddable Javascript engine` called [Duktape](https://duktape.org/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will try to use flutter_js package.

I'm developing iOS and Android app used by Flutter. Flutter Web is not developing. Those dart:js, js|dart packages can be used for Flutter Web app only?